# What is the correlation between system design and design patterns?

Tags: design-patterns, software-design, system-design

I am just getting started with system design and I would like to know what is the correlation between system design and design patterns?

Comment: There are design patterns which addresses different level of a software system. class level, component level, system level etc. What's your actual problem??

Comment: @SupunWijerathne This is more of a general problem. I just wanted to know how knowing design patterns helps in system designing. I believe system design takes into account issues such as scalability, architecture etc. So, where does design pattern comes into picture in system designing?

Answer (score 2):

If there is such a thing as "best system design", it is absolutely uncorrelated with the use of design patterns.

Design patterns are just names for recurring elements in software design. The idea is to improve communication and to avoid having to re-invent the wheel each time such an element occurs.

So the use of design patterns might save you time and can make the design easier to understand for other developers. But it doesn't neccessarily make it better or worse.

Answer (score 1):

A design pattern is a problem solution pair. i.e. it's a ready made solution for a common problem in software design.

But, it doesn't necessarily mean that in order to make a great design, you should be following some patterns. Most of the time , the problem we are trying to solve is more specific(**concrete**) than what we see in patterns. Therefore we need to **tailor** any pattern we are going to use.

On the other hand for a certain problem we are trying to solve, there can be number of ready made solutions. In that kind of a situation, we might need to consider the **trade-offs** of each. (ex: performance over maintainability, w.r.t. the situation, we need to make sure what we really want in our system)

One final thing, it's a **very bad** practice to try just drag and drop a pattern to the design we are making just for the sake of using a pattern, without knowing its real use. Those kinds of situations are the **worst** of all time. Actually over engineering is far more evil than under engineering. You should be able to identify that **sweet spot** where you can enjoy the goods of many different worlds. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Both are using for designing software products otherwise both are used completely in different context .

Answer (score 0):

Design pattern is a general and reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem within a given context in software design.

And system design is the process of defining the architecture, modules, interfaces, and data for a system to satisfy specified requirements.

System design is related to system analysis, system architecture, and system engineering but not with design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

System Design is the process of defining the building blocks of a system to resolve a defined problem. Building blocks of System Design include Architecture of the System, Modules, and Interfaces between the modules.

Design Patterns are "Descriptions of communicating objects and classes that are
customized to solve a general design problem in a particular context" (From GoF Design Patterns)

Answer (score 0):

System design is a collection of design decisions that affect the entire system.
The design pattern summarizes the solutions to frequent problems, usually applied to a part of the systems.